# How to scroll instantly a ScrollPane in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx

I would like to place the child actor at an initial position within the ScrollPane, but the scrollTo() method seems to only do a scroll animation, and doesn't allow to move the child actor instantly. Using the child actor's setPosition() has no effect too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call `updateVisualScroll()` after programmatically updating the scroll position